# H2OTypeError: Argument should be an ?integer, got int64 [3.30.1.1]

Tags: numpy, typeerror, xgboost, h2o, hyperopt

I'm trying a simple use of hyperopt with H2O XGBoost for which I'm taking elements out of a numpy array for the parameters, but I'm getting this H2OTypeError and I don't understand why the condition of `?integer` isn't met by `int64`.

To simplify the example, H2O XGBoost does work when called as:

```
xgb = H2OXGBoostEstimator(nfolds=5, max_depth=list(range(10,11))[0])
```

But the following returns this H2OTypeError:

```
xgb = H2OXGBoostEstimator(nfolds=5, max_depth=np.arange(10,11,1)[0])
```

...

```
H2OTypeError: Argument `max_depth` should be an ?integer, got int64
```

I can work around the error for now, but I don't understand it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

H2O is expecting a native Python `int`, but you are passing a `numpy int64`. More is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38156630/12441750) about the differences.

Try converting the numpy array into a list `max_depth=np.arange(10,11,1).tolist()[0]`