# Why do I observe difference between direct (manual) vs looped evaluation of summation?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I am evaluating an extensive summation, by evaluating each term separately using a for-loop (Python 3.5 + NumPy 1.15.4). However, I obtained a surprising result when comparing manual term-by-term evaluation vs. using the for-loop. See MWE below.

S = sum(c_i x^i) for i=0..n  ([properly formatted LaTeX version here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTDwP.png))

Main questions:

1. Where does the difference in the outputs y1 and y2 originate from?
2. How could I alter the code such that the for-loop yields the expected result (y1==y2)?

Comparing dy1 and dy2:

```
dy1:
[-1.76004137e-02  3.50290845e+01  1.50326037e+01 -7.25045852e+01
  2.08908445e+02 -3.31104542e+02  2.98005855e+02 -1.53154111e+02
  4.18203833e+01 -4.68961704e+00  0.00000000e+00]

dy2:
[-1.76004137e-02  3.50290845e+01  1.50326037e+01 -7.25045852e+01
 -3.27960559e-01 -4.01636743e-04  2.26525295e-07  4.80637463e-10
  1.93967535e-13 -1.93976497e-17 -0.00000000e+00]

dy1==dy2:
[ True  True  True  True False False False False False False  True]
```

Thanks!

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
coeff = np.array([
    [ 0.000000000000E+00, -0.176004136860E-01],
    [ 0.394501280250E-01,  0.389212049750E-01],
    [ 0.236223735980E-04,  0.185587700320E-04],
    [-0.328589067840E-06, -0.994575928740E-07],
    [-0.499048287770E-08,  0.318409457190E-09],
    [-0.675090591730E-10, -0.560728448890E-12],
    [-0.574103274280E-12,  0.560750590590E-15],
    [-0.310888728940E-14, -0.320207200030E-18],
    [-0.104516093650E-16,  0.971511471520E-22],
    [-0.198892668780E-19, -0.121047212750E-25],
    [-0.163226974860E-22,  0.000000000000E+00]
    ]).T

c = coeff[1]  # select appropriate coeffs
x = 900       # input

# manual calculation
y = c[0]*x**0 + c[1]*x**1 + c[2]*x**2 + c[3]*x**3 + c[4]*x**4 + \
    c[5]*x**5 + c[6]*x**6 + c[7]*x**7 + c[8]*x**8 + c[9]*x**9 + c[10]*x**10
print('y:',y)

# calc terms individually
dy1 = np.zeros(c.size)
dy1[0] = c[0]*x**0
dy1[1] = c[1]*x**1
dy1[2] = c[2]*x**2
dy1[3] = c[3]*x**3
dy1[4] = c[4]*x**4
dy1[5] = c[5]*x**5
dy1[6] = c[6]*x**6
dy1[7] = c[7]*x**7
dy1[8] = c[8]*x**8
dy1[9] = c[9]*x**9
dy1[10] = c[10]*x**10

# calc terms in for loop
dy2 = np.zeros(len(c))
for i in np.arange(len(c)):
    dy2[i] = c[i]*x**i

# summation and print
y1 = np.sum(dy1)
print('y1:',y1)
y2 = np.sum(dy2)
print('y2:',y2)
```

Output:

```
y: 37.325915370853856
y1: 37.32591537085385
y2: -22.788859384118823
```

Comment: How do the individual terms in `dy1` and `dy2` compare?

Comment: I've added these above

Comment: Weird behaviour, switching `np.arange(len(c))` to `range(len(c))` seems to fix the issue, but outputs of both methods look similar.

Comment: Strange, the first 4 are identical, and the others are totally different. Does this change for different values of `x`?

Comment: @dm2 Thanks for the quick fix! However, I would still like to know why `np.arange()` does not seem to be appropriate here. 
@mkrieger1 Larger values of `x` result in larger difference between `y1` and `y2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like raising a python `int` to a power of `numpy` integer (of specific size)  leads to conversion of result to a numpy integer of the same size.

**Example:**

```
type(900**np.int32(10))
```

returns `numpy.int32` and

```
type(900**np.int64(10))
```

returns `numpy.int64`

---

From this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38155039/what-is-the-difference-between-native-int-type-and-the-numpy-int-types) it seems that while Python `int` are variable sized, numpy integers are not (the size is specified by type as, for example, `np.int32` or `np.int64`). So, while Python `range` function returns integers of variable size (Python `int` type), `np.arange` returns integers of specific type (if not specified, type is inferred).

**Trying to compare the Python integer math vs numpy integer math:**

`900**10` returns `348678440100000000000000000000`

while `900**np.int32(10)` returns `-871366656`

Looks like you get integer overflow via `np.arange` function because the numpy integer dtype (in this case it is inferred as `np.int32`) is too small to store the resulting value.

---

**Edit:**

**In this specific case**, using `np.arange(len(c), dtype = np.uint64)` seems to output the right values:

```
dy2 = np.zeros(len(c))
for i in np.arange(len(c), dtype = np.uint64):
    dy2[i] = c[i]*x**i
dy1 == dy2
```

Outputs:

```
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True])
```

*Note:* the accuracy might suffer using numpy in this case (`int(900*np.uint64(10))` returns `348678440099999970966892445696` which is less than `900**10`), so if that is of importance, I'd still opt to use Python built-in `range` function.

Comment: Thanks for the additional explanation! So, then, in general just stick with `range()` instead of `np.arange()` !

Comment: Check my edit. There are nuances for different dtypes, so I'd encourage you too look into what you want to use specifically (although as mentioned, in this specific case, using `np.uint64` seems to work)

Comment: Great! Thanks again.

Comment: @ejok There is an "Accept" button near answer. You can use it

Comment: I've just reached the same conclusion.  Changing to `x = 900.` ( instead of  x = 900 ) means x is a float and the integer overflow doesn't happen

Comment: @TlsChris interesting find. However seems the accuracy suffers in that case (`900**10` outputs `348678440100000000000000000000` while `int(900.**np.int32(10))` outputs `348678440099999970966892445696`

Comment: `900**np.int64(10)` returns `-4356359181443268608`.  No numpy int type can cope with 900 ** 10  ( decimal 30 digits ). np.uint64 2**64 ( decimal 20 digits ).  The choice is stick with python ints or use np.floats.  The result of the exponentiation will be converted to a float for the `c[10]` multiplication anyway.

Comment: @TlsChris using `np.uint64`, the result is converted to `np.float64` using scientific notation , so yes, might as well use float (in this specific case accuracy was the same even with `np.float16`) from the get go (using floats looks to be the reason for inaccuracy on both cases, so I'd just stick to Python built-in `int` type anyways)